# Could not make the PowerShell Scriptlet work from C#

Tags: c#, powershell

I am trying to stop an application pool by issuing the below command from PowerShell

```
Stop-WebAppPool "Test1234"
```

This worked. I checked that the "Test1234" Application Pool has stopped.

However, when I made it as a test.ps1 file and invoked the same from my C# code, it didnot worked.

**C# Code**

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.FileName = @"powershell.exe";
startInfo.Arguments = @"& 'c:\test.ps1'";
startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
startInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
Process process = new Process();
process.StartInfo = startInfo;
process.Start();
```

It didn't throw any error but didn't worked. Why this happened and how to get that work?

Comment: why the command args "& 'c:\test.ps1'" surely its just "c:\test.ps1"

Comment: Errors raised in PowerShell are not often returned as a process-level exception (unless you explicitly use the "exit <level>" command in a script). Your test.ps1 script will need error handling and will need to do something with those errors so you can investigate. C# running a script in this manner has no visibility of the interior.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to invoke powershell from C#, you may consider using [System.Management.Automation](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Management.Automation) nuget package. As described in [msdn docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.powershell(v=vs.85).aspx), this nuget package will allow you to run powershell as follows:

```
using System.Management.Automation;
// ...
PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create();
ps.AddCommand("Stop-WebAppPool");
ps.AddArgument("Test1234");
ps.Invoke();
```